# How do I run ASP.NET Core Entity Framework migrations from Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-core

I've got a Web API project created using ASP.NET Core 1.1. I use Entity Framework Core Migrations. Locally, that all works well.

However, I'm trying to use Visual Studio team services to automatically run the migrations when I do a release and can't figure out how to do this. Is there some inbuilt component, or should I try to get the dotnet ef tools installed on the agent and run it that way?

Comment: Try to create a publish profile through VS with Migration configured, then publish web app to a package by using Visual Studio Build task with /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=CustomProfile;DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebAppCore.zip" argument, after that deploy this package to azure app.

Comment: As @starain-MSFT said. Remember to edit your csproj file manually and add the DotNetCli references appropriately. Currently you cannot add the Nuget packages for these. These allow you to use **dotnet ef** commands and allow you to setup the Publish wizard correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the dotnet ef tools (during VSTS Build) to generate a .sql script which could be used to generate or update your database wherever needed (during the Release).

```
dotnet ef migrations script -o migration-script.sql -i -v
```

During Release amongst other options you could run Invoke-SqlCmd:

```
Invoke-SqlCmd -inputfile "$inputFile" -serverinstance "$serverInstance" -username "$serverUserName" -password "$serverPassword" -database "$database"
```