# VSTS Build How to Add update-database command for EF Core Code First

Tags: entity-framework, azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I use VSTS and Git as source controller and Azure as host to my ASP.NET Core 2.1 API application, I'm trying to have a CI in VSTS, So every things worked except automatically update-database, I used EF core Code first and I need to update DB (in Azure) Automatically in CI process.

But For now, each time I update the connection string in my project(to Azure DB) and run the update-database manually.

For automatic CI process I find:

- [Using Migration.exe in TFSBuild](https://www.benday.com/2016/11/07/using-tfs-build-to-deploy-entity-framework-database-migrations-with-migrate-exe/)
- [How to UPDATE DATABASE in Code First approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46280237/how-to-update-database-in-code-first-approach-automatically-after-check-in-and-p)

So I search in Debug Console to find package folder irst to set the command to use packages/migration.exe

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureAppServices.SiteExtension\store\x86\netcoreapp2.1

[image]

I can't find any package folder, or entifyframework libraries

So how could I find the migration.exe file?

Is there any other way to have automatic update-database in VSTS build for EF Code first?

**UPDATE:**

Here is my nuget reference:

[image]

I add the copy file step:

[image]

And config is:

[image]

Bu I got the Error:

[image]

It seems the source folder path is not correct, What should I add as a Source folder?

Comment: The blog posts you linked give pretty explicit step-by-step instructions. What isn't working with them? Migrate.exe is part of the NuGet package, it's not necessarily going to be packaged up and deployed in your webdeploy package.

Comment: @DanielMann, I update the question, I don't know what should I set as a source folder?

Comment: Do you try to migration during deployment process? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46784150/ef-core-code-first-deployment-vsts-pipeline-hospolicy-dll. Another thread that my benefit you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44746103/how-do-i-run-asp-net-core-entity-framework-migrations-from-visual-studio-team-se/46906087

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you can do migration during deploy process:

1. Configure your web core project with EF migration: [Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations?view=aspnetcore-2.1)
2. Create a publish profile with Entity Framework Migrations (Settings > Entity Framework Migrations)
3. Include the publish profile to source control (include pubxml.user file to source control or copy **ItemGroup** section (`<ItemGroup><EFMigrations …`) to your publish profile (.pubxml))
4. Publish web app through Visual Studio Build task (MSBuild Arguments: `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=CustomProfile;DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\myapp.zip"`)
5. Deploy package (step4) to your site (e.g. through WinRM-IIS Web App Deployment task or Azure App Service Deploy task)

Comment: Regarding step 4: What are the consequences of replacing `dotnet build` with Visual Studio Build task? how will be rest of the build pipeline affected? e.g. what to do with `dotnet publish` task

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to run dotnet ef update in during deploy, so that I don't have to change the build definition too much from the default one,

Comment: @Liero did you find a solution to this? I'm currently experimenting with my build

Comment: @Adrian: No, I didn't :(